# $A \cong D \subseteq B$ and $B/D \cong C$, is there any operation s.t $B$ can be "constructed" by combining $A$ and $C$ with that operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, modules

Let for any sets $A,B,C$ having the same algebraic structure (they can be groups, rings, modules, etc.)
$$0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$$
be a short exact sequence with $f: A \to B$ and $g: B\to C$ s.t $Im (f) = Ker (g)$.

It is clear that $B$ has a *substructure* that is algebraically equivalent (isomorphic) to $A$ s.t when we consider the *quotient* of that substructure with $B$, it is algebraically equivalent (isomorphic) to $C$.

Is there any algebraic structure and a operation between such structures that we can "construct" $B$ out of $A$ and $C$ ? In other words, is there any algebraic structure and an operation on the set of all such algebraic structures, denote $+$, $A+C$ is algebraically equivalent to $B$ ?

**Edit:**

Note that, I looking for something a general way of "constructing" $B$ out of $A$ and $C$ s.t we can do this "construction" what ever $A,B,C$ is as long as they have that algebraic structure.

Comment: One valid candidate for $B$ is $A\oplus C$, but in fact $B$ need not be isomorphic to it. In the case of **Grp**, any semidirect product would works as well, and even that covers only the cases when the sequence splits

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks for the comment; however, I'm having trouble understanding your comment, so I would appreciate if you could expand it a bit.

Comment: With $A=C=\mathbb Z/2$, we could have $B=(\mathbb Z/2)\oplus(\mathbb Z/2)$ or we could have $B=\mathbb Z/4$. (This is just the simplest of a vast variety of examples, as indicated by Hagen von Eitzen.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, but I was looking for something more general; not just a specific example.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen See my edit, also.

Answer (score 1):

There cannot be the operation that you wish on the nose, because, as Andreas Blass points out in the comments, in most of these categories there are *non-trivial extensions*, i.e. there is more than one way to fit an object $\square$ in an exact sequence
$$
0 \to A \to \square \to C \to 0.
$$

However, you can make a group out of an "exact category" (the so called Grothendieck group, where "exact category" roughly means there's enough structure to make sense of short exact sequences in the category). The idea is to take as elements of the group all (isomorphism classes of) objects and formally identifying $A + C = B$ whenever
$$
0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0.
$$
See (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_group#Grothendieck_group_and_extensions) for details.